# Angular: Passed params in nested directive is of state "undefined"

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

We are following an example from http://mfauveau.github.io/angular-query-builder/ and modifying it to fit into our requirement.

We have a modal view(.jsp) that has integrated directive **(named as 'querybuilder', Yellow part in the picture - a js file)**. Controller(named as 'addEditRuleSetCtrl') and directive is included from upper level and inclusion seems fine.

**We have initiated the directive from the view (.jsp file)as :**

```
<div ng-init="addEditRuleSetCtrl.initSelectors()">
            <query-builder group="addEditRuleSetCtrl.filter.group"
                           rule-condition-operators="addEditRuleSetCtrl.ruleConditionOperators"
                           rule-condition-set-operators="addEditRuleSetCtrl.ruleConditionSetOperators"
                           fields="addEditRuleSetCtrl.getCorrespondingFields()"
                           ></query-builder>
</div>
```

**And we have included the template for the directive in view/.jsp as (notice that the directive is initiated here again when new group is created):**

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/queryBuilderDirective.html">
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-group">
    <div class="form-inline">
        <select ng-options="o as o.operator for o in ruleConditionSetOperators" ng-model="group.operator" class="form-control input-sm"></select>
        <button style="margin-left: 5px" ng-click="addCondition()" class="btn btn-sm btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> Add Condition</button>
        <button style="margin-left: 5px" ng-click="addGroup()" class="btn btn-sm btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> Add Group</button>
        <button style="margin-left: 5px" ng-click="removeGroup()" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></span> Remove Group</button>
    </div>
    <div class="group-conditions">
        <div ng-repeat="rule in group.rules | orderBy:'index'" class="condition">
            <div ng-switch="rule.hasOwnProperty('group')">
                <div ng-switch-when="true">
                        <query-builder group="rule.group"
                                       rule-condition-operators="addEditRuleSetCtrl.ruleConditionOperators"
                                       rule-condition-set-operators="addEditRuleSetCtrl.ruleConditionSetOperators"
                                       fields="addEditRuleSetCtrl.getCorrespondingFields()"
                        ></query-builder>
                </div>
                <div ng-switch-default="ng-switch-default">
                    <div class="form-inline">
                        <select ng-options="t.name as t.name for t in fields" ng-model="rule.field" class="form-control input-sm"></select>
                        <select style="margin-left: 5px" ng-options="c as c.operator for c in ruleConditionOperators" ng-model="rule.condition" class="form-control input-sm"></select>
                        <input style="margin-left: 5px" type="text" ng-model="rule.data" class="form-control input-sm"/>
                        <button style="margin-left: 5px" ng-click="removeCondition($index)" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></span></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Our problem is :** the first layer of the tree/group has right value of all the parameters(fields,rule-condition-set-operators,rule-condition-operators). Hence, in the first layer , all the associated dropdowns have displayed right values. But when I click the button "add group" in  the first layer, all the params are now "undefined" and hence all the dropdowns starting from the 2nd layer is empty **( showed by the red arrow sign in the picture)**.

**Questions are :**

1. Is that correct that starting from the 2nd layer of group, the
   params are out of scope of the controller because they are defined
   outside the view block?
2. How to make the params available to all layers of the group?

**Here is the view (.jsp file):**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<link 
    href="<c:url value='aviato/ruleEngine/addEditRuleSet/css/addeditruleset.css' />"
    rel="stylesheet">
</link>

<%--<script src="aviato/ruleEngine/addEditRuleSet/directive/addEditRuleSet_directive.js"></script>--%>

<form name="addEditRuleSetModalForm" novalidate class="modal-dialog">

    <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">
                {{addEditRuleSetCtrl.windowHeader}}
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm pull-right"
                        ng-click="addEditRuleSetCtrl.close()" data-toggle="uibtooltip" title="Cancel" >
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span>
                </button>
            </h4>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
            Hello world [origin] : {{ addEditRuleSetCtrl.origin }}
            <br />
            Hello world [iceField] : {{ addEditRuleSetCtrl.iceField }}
            Output: {{ addEditRuleSetCtrl.output }}

            <div class="alert alert-info">
                <strong>Example Output</strong><br>
                Output: {{ addEditRuleSetCtrl.output }}
            </div>

            <div ng-init="addEditRuleSetCtrl.initSelectors()">
                <query-builder group="addEditRuleSetCtrl.filter.group"
                               rule-condition-operators="addEditRuleSetCtrl.ruleConditionOperators"
                               rule-condition-set-operators="addEditRuleSetCtrl.ruleConditionSetOperators"
                               fields="addEditRuleSetCtrl.getCorrespondingFields()"
                               ></query-builder>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button"  class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="addEditRuleSetCtrl.test()" data-toggle="tooltip" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign" ></span></button><span></span>
        </div>

    </div>

</form>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="/queryBuilderDirective.html">
    <div class="alert alert-warning alert-group">
        <div class="form-inline">
            <select ng-options="o as o.operator for o in ruleConditionSetOperators" ng-model="group.operator" class="form-control input-sm"></select>
            <button style="margin-left: 5px" ng-click="addCondition()" class="btn btn-sm btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> Add Condition</button>
            <button style="margin-left: 5px" ng-click="addGroup()" class="btn btn-sm btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> Add Group</button>
            <button style="margin-left: 5px" ng-click="removeGroup()" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></span> Remove Group</button>
        </div>
        <div class="group-conditions">
            <div ng-repeat="rule in group.rules | orderBy:'index'" class="condition">
                <div ng-switch="rule.hasOwnProperty('group')">
                    <div ng-switch-when="true">
                            <query-builder group="rule.group"
                                           rule-condition-operators="addEditRuleSetCtrl.ruleConditionOperators"
                                           rule-condition-set-operators="addEditRuleSetCtrl.ruleConditionSetOperators"
                                           fields="addEditRuleSetCtrl.getCorrespondingFields()"
                            ></query-builder>
                    </div>
                    <div ng-switch-default="ng-switch-default">
                        <div class="form-inline">
                            <select ng-options="t.name as t.name for t in fields" ng-model="rule.field" class="form-control input-sm"></select>
                            <select style="margin-left: 5px" ng-options="c as c.operator for c in ruleConditionOperators" ng-model="rule.condition" class="form-control input-sm"></select>
                            <input style="margin-left: 5px" type="text" ng-model="rule.data" class="form-control input-sm"/>
                            <button style="margin-left: 5px" ng-click="removeCondition($index)" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></span></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

**The Directive (.js file):**

```
AddEditRuleSetApp.directive('queryBuilder', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            group: '=',
            ruleConditionOperators: '=',
            ruleConditionSetOperators: '=',
            fields: '='

        },

        templateUrl: '/queryBuilderDirective.html',
        compile: function (element, attrs) {
            var content, directive;
            content = element.contents().remove();
            return function (scope, element, attrs) {


                scope.addCondition = function () {

                    window.alert("[addCondition] : " + "group : " + JSON.stringify( scope.group) + "...BREAK..."
                                             +"fields : " + JSON.stringify( scope.ruleConditionOperators) + "...BREAK..."
                                             +"Condition : "+JSON.stringify(scope.ruleConditionOperators) + "...BREAK..."
                                             +"Condition set: "+JSON.stringify(scope.ruleConditionSetOperators));
                    scope.group.rules.push({
                        condition: '=',
                        field: 'Firstname',
                        data: ''
                    });
                };

                scope.removeCondition = function (index) {
                    scope.group.rules.splice(index, 1);
                };

                scope.addGroup = function () {

                    window.alert("[addGroup] :"  + "group : " + JSON.stringify( scope.group) + "...BREAK..."
                        +" fields : " + JSON.stringify( scope.fields) + "...BREAK..."
                        +"Condition : "+JSON.stringify(scope.ruleConditionOperators) + "...BREAK..."
                        +"Condition set: "+JSON.stringify(scope.ruleConditionSetOperators));

                    scope.group.rules.push({
                        group: {
                            operator: 'AND',
                            rules: []
                        }
                    });
                };

                scope.removeGroup = function () {
                    "group" in scope.$parent && scope.$parent.group.rules.splice(scope.$parent.$index, 1);
                };

                directive || (directive = $compile(content));

                element.append(directive(scope, function ($compile) {
                    return $compile;
                }));
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

**The controller :**

```
AddEditRuleSetApp.controller( 'AddEditRuleSetModalController', [ '$scope', '$rootScope', '$uibModalInstance','RuleEngineService', 'origin', 'iceField','FileService',
    function( $scope, $rootScope , $uibModalInstance, RuleEngineService, origin, iceField, FileService )
        {
            var self = this;
            self.origin = origin;
            self.iceField = iceField;

            self.data = '{"group": {"operator": "AND","rules": []}}';
            self.output = 'bologna';

            self.fieldsDDE = [
                { name: 'FirstnameDDE' },
                { name: 'LastnameDDE' },
                { name: 'BirthdateDDE' },
                { name: 'CityDDE' },
                { name: 'CountryDDE' }
            ];

            self.fieldsATT = [
                { name: 'FirstnameATT' },
                { name: 'LastnameATT' },
                { name: 'BirthdateATT' },
                { name: 'CityATT' },
                { name: 'CountryATT' }
            ];

            self.ruleConditionSetOperators = [
            ];

            self.ruleConditionOperators = [
                           ];

            self.filter = JSON.parse(self.data);

            self.initSelectors  = function()
            {
                self.getRuleConditionOperators();
                self.getRuleConditionSetOperators();
            }

            self.getRuleConditionOperators = function()
            {
               if ( self.ruleConditionOperators.length == 0 )
                {

                     RuleEngineService.getAllRuleConditionOperators()
                         .then(
                             function( d )
                             {
                                self.ruleConditionOperators = d;
                             },
                             function( errResponse )
                             {
                             console.error( 'Error while fetching rule-condition-operators' );
                             }
                         );
                }
                return self.ruleConditionOperators;

            };

            self.getRuleConditionSetOperators = function()
            {
                if ( self.ruleConditionSetOperators.length == 0 )
                {

                    RuleEngineService.getAllRuleConditionSetOperators()
                        .then(
                            function( d )
                            {
                                self.ruleConditionSetOperators = d;
                            },
                            function( errResponse )
                            {
                                console.error( 'Error while fetching rule-condition-operators' );
                            }
                        );
                }
                return self.ruleConditionSetOperators;

            };


            self.htmlEntities = function(str)
            {
                return String(str).replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
            };


            self.displayErrorMessages = false;
            self.createSuccess = '';
            self.createHeader = '';
            self.backendErr = "";

            self.windowHeader = "Create/Edit Rule Group";


            self.close = function()
            {
                $uibModalInstance.close();
            };

            self.getCorrespondingFields = function()
            {
               // window.alert("---------------Reached client side controller to getCorrespondingFields");
                return self.origin == 'DDE' ? self.fieldsDDE : self.fieldsATT;
            };

            self.computed = function(group)
            {
                window.alert("Inside controller: computed");

                if (!group) return "";
                for (var str = "(", i = 0; i < group.rules.length; i++) {
                    i > 0 && (str += " <strong>" + group.operator + "</strong> ");
                    str += group.rules[i].group ?
                        self.computed(group.rules[i].group) :
                        group.rules[i].field + " " +
                        //htmlEntities(group.rules[i].condition)
                        group.rules[i].condition
                        + " " + group.rules[i].data;
                }

                return str + ")";
            };


            $scope.$watch('filter', function (newValue)
            {
                self.output = self.computed(newValue);
            }, true);

            self.test = function()
            {
                window.alert(JSON.stringify( self.filter) );
            };

        } 
    ]);
```

The screenshot:

[image]

May I get any help here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my workaround (Addeed this to the directive) and that helped:

```
scope.fieldCodes = scope.$parent.fieldCodes;
scope.ruleConditionOperators = scope.$parent.ruleConditionOperators;
scope.ruleConditionSetOperators = scope.$parent.ruleConditionSetOperators;
```

So, the directive now looks like:

```
AddEditRuleSetApp.directive('queryBuilder', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            group: '=',
            ruleConditionOperators: '=',
            ruleConditionSetOperators: '=',
            fieldCodes: '='

        },

        templateUrl: '/queryBuilderDirective.html',
        compile: function (element, attrs) {
            var content, directive;
            content = element.contents().remove();
            return function (scope, element, attrs) {


                scope.fieldCodes = scope.$parent.fieldCodes;
                scope.ruleConditionOperators = scope.$parent.ruleConditionOperators;
                scope.ruleConditionSetOperators = scope.$parent.ruleConditionSetOperators;

                scope.addCondition = function () {

                    scope.group.rules.push({
                        condition: '=',
                        field: 'Firstname',
                        data: ''
                    });
                };

                scope.removeCondition = function (index) {
                    scope.group.rules.splice(index, 1);
                };

                scope.addGroup = function () {

                    scope.group.rules.push({
                        group: {
                            operator: 'AND',
                            rules: []
                        }
                    });
                };

                scope.removeGroup = function () {
                    "group" in scope.$parent && scope.$parent.group.rules.splice(scope.$parent.$index, 1);
                };



                directive || (directive = $compile(content));

                element.append(directive(scope, function ($compile) {
                    return $compile;
                }));
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```